Infrequent wifi every 3 month just about
My Internet company has sent me 3 new boxes for my wifi/Internet due to me complaining about my signal going in and out over the last 6 months. They cannot give me a reason why. I connected my new box today all was working till 6pm when wifi started again going in n out on this new different updated box. I am wondering if someone in this apartment complex has a signal scrambler. Any ideas?

Hi, welcome to SuperUser. A tip for asking good tech help questions online: Technical questions require  technical details. In this case that means things like what residential broadband internet service technology you're using, and the brand and model#'s of the devices involved. You won't be able to get good help unless you provide sufficient technical details in your Question post. See How To Ask Questions The Smart Way for more guidance on how to ask tech questions well so you get good answers quickly.

When the wifi has issues, have you tried using a hardwired connection? If not, I would try that. It will help you determine if it's wifi signal related or something else.

Try a tool such as Nirsoft's WiFiInfoView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html, to see what channel(s) are in use, and to try selecting another.

Its unlikely that someone is using a scrambler that would affect your Wifi.
A few possibly causes

Your internet from the ISP is dicey.
The power in your apartment is dicey.

Both can get worse when there is more load on, when people are back home.

Its a lot more likely there is competition for the WIFI spectrum then it being a power issue.  The internet from the ISP being dicey is a possibility, but quite a bit less likely then WIFI problems - which are common.

Thank you @davidgo

It is important to understand that "WIFI" bands are relatively unregulated, and it is quite possible that your neighbours usage could be affecting yours.  This does not typically imply a signal scrambler, just someone elses use of the spectrum - which they are entitled to do.   You might want to advise what kind of router(s) you have/had
Its also worth considering that - generally speaking - ISP routers/boxes are made to a price point and are generally not great from a WIFI POV.  Getting more premium hardware will often solve/mitigate your issues - especially if you look towards newer (802.11ax - WIFI 6) standard devices which both have more bandwidth and better ways of managing it - of-course this works best if both the router and the devices it connects to are WIFI6 (but may well provide some benefit even if the client is not).
Something that might help as well - get a signal strength analyzer app for your cellphone - this can often tell how good your connectivity is in various locations and also show other access points which can help show you how busy your spectrum is.
It is also possible that something is generating noise in the WIFI spectrum - this will not be picked up by your phone analyzer - sometimes fridges/microwaves/baby monitors are not nice.    If you use the 5 gig band (rather then rely on 2.4) your range is shorter, but conversely you have less interference [because range is shorter] and more spectrum, so more throughput.
If its practical, relocating the router to more central point in your apartment or adding an Access point can help with coverage.
ALL THIS ASSUMES THE PROBLEM IS WIFI - Which is reasonable but not guaranteed.  You may want to check if wired connections also suffer performance issues - in which case WIFI is a red herring.

Thank you, I will check on your suggestions
